# Why can I not use std::cin twice even if I used clean and sync methods?

Tags: c++

I am learning the iostream library in C++. I wrote a short program using it. I used the `cin>>variable` as a condition of a  `while` loop. After the `while` loop, I used the `clear()` and `sync()` methods so that I can use `cin` again after I reached EOF. However, `cin` does not work. This puzzled me very much. I can't figure out the solution.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int j=0;
    std::string buf;
    while (std::cin >> buf)
        std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
    std::cin>>j;
    std::cout<<j<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HuXixi when the loop consists of a single statement, the braces are optional

Comment: What is your OS, compiler, and input device? How exactly do you run your program?

Comment: @n.m. My OS is macOS 10.14 , compiler is Clang 10.0.1,I used CMake to arrange my codes(though there was only one file)

Comment: You cannot do that in OS X. The system closes the connection to the terminal. No input is sent to your program. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872069/cin-clear-not-working-in-mac

Comment: @HuXixi -- many of us find unneeded curly braces to be a distraction. Don't try to impose your personal judgments about style on people around you unless that's your job.